# Parallel Mulit-threaded Downloads using async-await

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I have 100s of multiple big files to download from web in my windows service - C#. The requirement is to maintain at one time - max 4 parallel web file downloads.

Can I achieve concurrent/parallel downloads using async await or do I have to use `BackgroundWorker` process or threads ? Is async-await multithreaded ?
See my sample Program using async-await below:

```
 static int i = 0;
 
 Timer_tick() {
   while (i < 4) {
     i++;
     model = GetNextModel();
     await Download(model);
   }
 }
 
 private async Download(XYZ model) {
   Task<FilesetResult> t = DoWork(model);
   result = await t;
   //Use Result
 }
 
 private async Task<FilesetResult> Work(XYZ model) {
   fileresult = await api.Download(model.path)
   i--;
   return filesetresult;
 }
```

Comment: Yes, but you'd have to not `await` the downloads one by one, but instead initiate the number you want and use `Task.WaitAll`, before moving on to the next batch.  But it's not multi threaded.  It's just going to allow the IO to happen in parallel, but everything CPU bound would be handled by one thread.  If you have CPU intensive code as well then you'd want a parallel solution as well.

Comment: If IO happens in parallel but only one thread is used, would using multiple threads increase performance ?

Comment: Completely depends on what else you do other than IO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can limit number of async tasks running in parallel using `SemaphoreSlim` class.  Something like:

```
List<DownloadRequest> requests = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(x => new DownloadRequest()).ToList();
using (var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(4))
{
    Task<DownloadResult>[] downloadTasks = requests.Select(request => Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await throttler.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            return await DownloadTaskAsync(request);
        }
        finally
        {
            throttler.Release();
        }
    })).ToArray();
    await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks);
}
```

**Update**: thank you for comments, fixed issues.

**Update2**: Sample solution for dynamic list of requests

```
public class DownloadManager : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(4);

    public async Task<DownloadResult> DownloadAsync(DownloadRequest request)
    {
        await _throttler.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            return await api.Download(request);
        }
        finally
        {
            _throttler.Release();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _throttler?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: My downloadrequests list is dynamic , it increases or decreases in size with time

Comment: The Task instance returned by Task.Run is not awaited, meaning that finally will be hit immediately (most likely while DownloadTaskAsync is still in progress) and the semaphore will be released. Without the returned task being added to the list and awaited at some point this solution is pure overhead - it doesn't do anything meaningful whatsoever

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy You are absolutely right, was writing that quickly in SO and forgot about it. Updated code. Also that quick snippet doesn't show how to handle download task results.

Comment: And now it's not parallel at all.

Comment: That's awaiting each download one by one.  It should instead initiate all of the ones for one batch, then use `Task.WaitAll`.

Comment: @juharr Yes, enough quick edits. Will do proper one now )

Comment: @Gags Added solution for dynamic requests when multiple clients may invoke download method, but some would wait until others are finished.

Comment: @juharr So, if there are 5 requests, 4 of them would run and the 5th one will wait at this lineawait _throttler.WaitAsync();

Comment: @Gags yes, and 5th one will continue after first tasks release semaphore

Comment: The `DownloadManager` implementation is pretty neat. I like how it puts the responsibility for observing exceptions back onto the caller. Since this is a download manager, you'd expect requests to fail periodically, and that's something `Task.WhenAll(...)` won't work well with - but if you just return a `Task` reference to the caller like your `DownloadManager` implementation does, they can then handle each individual failure gracefully.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy Thanks. For real life I would also add a Cancellation token support there as well, which can be applied for Semaphore waiting as well as api downloading.

Comment: @dlxeon  When I call multiple DownloadAsync(request) in my timer_tick event, if I use DownloadAsync(request).Wait(), execution will be awaited, which I do not want. So should I use a synchronous call to DownloadAsync(request). Will that provide concurrent downloads.

Comment: @gags using .Wait() effectively means to block caller thread. If you want to use in parallel you should either have async/await callers or you need to start multiple tasks and wait them at once (1st code sample)

Answer (score 3):

Doing it by hand seems awfully complicated.

```
var files = new List<Uri>();

Parallel.ForEach(files, 
                 new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
                 this.Download);
```

Now all you need is a single, normal, synchronous method `private void Download(Uri file)` and you are good to go.

If you need a producer/consumer pattern, the easiest version might be a `BlockingCollection`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp11
{
    internal class Program
    {
        internal static void Main()
        {
            using (var queue = new BlockingCollection<Uri>())
            {
                // starting the producer task:
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                    {
                        // faking read from message queue... we get a new Uri every 100 ms
                        queue.Add(new Uri("http://www.example.com/" + i));

                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }

                    // just to end this program... you don't need to end this, just listen to your message queue
                    queue.CompleteAdding();
                });

                // run the consumers:
                Parallel.ForEach(queue.GetConsumingEnumerable(), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, Download);
            }
        }

        internal static void Download(Uri uri)
        {
            // download your file here

            Console.WriteLine($"Downloading {uri} [..        ]");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine($"Downloading {uri} [.....     ]");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine($"Downloading {uri} [.......   ]");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine($"Downloading {uri} [......... ]");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine($"Downloading {uri} [..........]");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine($"Downloading {uri} OK");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My List<Uri> keeps on increasing from Message Queue. Say when Parallel.ForEach has started it is 3 in size. When downloads are running 3 more requests are queued/added to List<uri>

Comment: You can use a `BlockingCollection<>` instead of a `List<>` then,