# DownloadFileTaskAsync does not work to download thousands of file

Tags: c#, webclient

I have a thousands list of download url. The url may contain a different type of file such as that image, pdf, audio, video etc. I am trying to download them using DownloadFileTaskAsync. But after several files downloading the app is breaking down. I don't understand what is happening.  don't get any error message. Just my app is shut down after few files downloading.

```
foreach (var url in urls)
{
    //if file exists in our local directory then do not need to download and continue the process...
    if (FileExistsOrNot(localPath + "/" + url.fileName))
       continue;

    Thread thread = new Thread(async () => {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
        await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url.downloadUrl), localPath + "/" + url.fileName);  
    });
    thread.Start();
}
```

Comment: `DownloadFileTaskAsync` already promises to do the work in the background (and [not use *any* threads](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)). Why are you creating new threads *just to set up the download*?

Comment: Also, you're subscribing two event handlers for events which *are not fired* by `DownloadFileTaskAsync`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I saw one thing. When my file name contains any space then the problem is happened and crash the app.

Comment: Actually is this a real problem that my file name contain space? @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: Well, since you're the only person who knows what values you're currently feeding into this code, you're the only one who can isolate the common patterns of failures. Bad space handling does seem a likely one though.

Comment: Actually, the bunch of urls comes from my client. I don't have access on this.

Comment: Creating thousands of threads is not a good idea - earlier or later you will get OutOfMemoryException. Also OS won't be able to efficiently schedule so many threads. Connections to servers are likely to be disconnected due to packets dropped in jammed internet connection. Plenty of questions on SO addresses this, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50330471/parallel-mulit-threaded-downloads-using-async-await). You also need to properly handle exceptions thrown on downloading threads, because any unhandled exception on a thread immediately terminates you application.

Comment: @Nuf Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: First you do not have an exception handler to indicate if the error is happening in the application.  Second most webservers so not allow multiple connections from same IP to prevent service attacks.  So the server is probably shutting you  down because it thinks you application is an attack.

Answer (score 1):

Spawning a new thread for every download it's no wonder that you quickly run out of system resources (threads in this case).

You should use some kind of thread pooling and luckily, C# has multiple out-of-the-box solution to do this:

- ThreadPool - [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem)
- Parallel Programming - [Parallel.ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach)
- Tasks + TaskScheduler - [Task.WhenAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall)

ThreadPool is the lowest level construct,  parallel programming and task schedulers are built on top of that.

As you use an async operation to download (*DownloadFileTaskAsync*), tasks are the most suitable option in this case:

```
Action<string, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs> onDownloadProgress = (url, e) => 
{ 
    /* your logic displaying progress... */ 
};

var downloadTasks = urls
    .Where(url => !FileExistsOrNot(Path.Combine(localPath, url.fileName)))
    .Select(async url =>
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => onDownloadProgress(url.fileName, e);
            try { await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url.downloadUrl), Path.Combine(localPath, url.fileName)); }
            catch (Exception ex) { /* handle download error: log exception, etc */ }                
        }
    });    

Task.WaitAll(downloadTasks.ToArray()); // or Task.WhenAll(...) if you want it non-blocking
```

Some remarks:

- use *Path.Combine* to build path strings to get correct results on every platform
- *WebClient* implements *IDisposable*, that is, it may use unmanaged resources. You should call *Dispose* on it as soon as you don't need it anymore, otherwise you can run out of system resources again.
- you don't need to observe *DownloadFileCompleted*. Awaiting *DownloadFileTaskAsync* rethrows potential errors as exceptions.
- consider using [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) instead of WebClient for better async support and performance